# Error: File contains parsing errors: file://///etc/yum.repos.d/dag.repo

Tags: repository, ffmpeg

I read you have to be careful with repo files for security with third party ones added.

Anyway I have simply been trying to install `ffmpeg` and I am stuck because yum
doesn't like what it is reading from the repo files and since I don't have a real understanding of what these files do I can't make logical sense of it.

At first I followed Linux blog which suggested create one repo file in `/etc/yum.repos.d/` and named it `ffmpeg.repo` and placed the following script in it:

```
[ffmpeg]
   name=FFmpeg RPM Repository for Red Hat Enterprise Linux
   baseurl=http://apt.sw.be/redhat/el6/en/x86_64/dag/  (64 Bit OS)
   #baseurl=http://apt.sw.be/redhat/el6/en/i386/dag/   (32 Bit OS)
   gpgcheck=1
   enabled=1
```

I couldn't get to work so went back to the file and removed empty spaces at beginning which at least enabled yum to output the error.

Then I tried renaming `ffmpeg.repo` to `dag.repo` and added following:

```
[dag]
name=Dag RPM Repository for Red Hat Enterprise Linux
baseurl=http://apt.sw.be/redhat/el6/en/x86_64/dag/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=http://apt.sw.be/RPM-GPG-KEY.dag.txt
enabled=1
includepkgs=ffmpeg ffmpeg-* faac a52dec x264 opencore-amr lame librtmp    schroedinger libva dirac orc
```

Then created a `centos.repo` file in same directory as suggested by another LINUX blog and added the following:

```
[centos]
name=CentOS-6 – Base
baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/os/x86_64/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6
enabled=1
priority=1
protect=1
includepkgs=SDL libtheora gsm libdc1394 libdrm liboil mesa-dri-drivers mesa-     dri1-drivers mesa-dri-filesystem libraw1394 libpciaccess cppunit
```

Anyway the error repeats itself and I cannot install `ffmpeg`.

```
bash-4.1# ls
CentOS-Base.repo       CentOS-Vault.repo  mirrors-rpmforge-extras
CentOS-Debuginfo.repo  ffmpeg.repo        mirrors-rpmforge-testing
CentOS-Media.repo      mirrors-rpmforge   rpmforge.repo

bash-4.1# yum update
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Repository 'ffmpeg': Error parsing config: Error parsing "baseurl =     'http://apt.sw.be/redhat/el6/en/x86_64/dag/  (64 Bit OS)'": URL must be http,    ftp, file or https not ""
  Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
  * rpmforge: mirror.ventraip.net.au
 rpmforge                                                 | 1.9 kB     00:00     
  rpmforge/primary_db                                      | 2.8 MB         00:04     
  Setting up Update Process
```

Answer (score 8):

You need to take out the spaces in the file. Make it look like this:

```
[ffmpeg]
name=FFmpeg RPM Repository for Red Hat Enterprise Linux
baseurl=http://apt.sw.be/redhat/el6/en/x86_64/dag/
#baseurl=http://apt.sw.be/redhat/el6/en/i386/dag/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
```

Also the error is fairly clear. There are syntax errors in the `dag.repo` file. I'm not sure what's what from your question. What is the current state of your `/etc/yum.repo.d` directory and what the contents of the files are there. But you need to get that directory under control.

I'd suggest getting the files out of there that are not in use, since they'll continue to dog you in messing up the rest of your YUM installation.

**NOTE1:** Every repo should have their own `.repo` file, do not mix the contents of the repos in a single file!

**NOTE2:** If you do not understand what you're doing with this directory I highly suggest you not mess with it in such a haphazard way. You can definitely get your system into a screwed up state where your only way out will be to do a full install again. I've been using Red Hat distros for 20+ years, please heed this advice!

**NOTE3:** Also when dealing with 3rd party repos (that's what all these files are pointing to in this directory - that you've been editing), it's generally best to utilize the repositories using the front door method vs. editing these files.

For example, the `apt.sw.be` URL you're attempting to point to is officially known as the RepoForge and has an actual RPM you can download and install to activate this repo.

You can read about its usage here:

- http://repoforge.org/use/